# Vanity url redirection from nginx with @ in url

Tags: nginx

I want to redirect mysite.com/@parag to mysite.com/#/conversation/parag

Below is the nginx configuration I have written but not working. What could I be doing wrong.

```
location ~ /\@ {
  rewrite ^/\@(.*)$ /#/conversation/$1 break;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `permanent` or `redirect` instead of `break`?

Comment: As @AlexeyTen said, using `permanent` or `redirect` will make nginx return 301 or 302 response with header "Location: http:\\mysite.com/#/conversation/parag" to browser. In such case, if it still does not work, there may be something wrong with handling `/#/conversation/parag`.

Answer (score 1):

If there is another location to capture uri /#/conversation/, use

```
rewrite ^/\@(.*)$ /#/conversation/$1 last;
```

instead of

```
rewrite ^/\@(.*)$ /#/conversation/$1 break;
```

See [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for rewrite flags.

Comment: @ParagArora, could you show other part of your nginx.conf, in which case we can know whether rewrite redirecting does not work or there is another problem.